# How to set initial position between two links connected via a floating joint?

Tags: urdf, robot-description

When I try to use the origin tag withing the joint, it doesn't affect the child link position.
How can I change the initial position of the floated link?

````
<link name="world" />

    <link name="test">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.0 0.4 0.1" />
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        </visual>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="10"/>
            <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
          </inertial>

    </link>

    <joint name="test_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world" />
        <child link="test" />
        <!-- This line doesn't affect anything -->
        <origin xyz="0 0 1" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Try adding a visual component to the world link so you can see it move.

```
<robot>
  <link name="world" >
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="test_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link="test" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 2" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

  <link name="test">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.0 0.4 0.1" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```